# Latent semantics and eigenvalues of the SVD

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

Maybe a strange question :-) trying to figure out the relation with eigenvalues and the documents/words of and LSI? since $Av = \lambda v$, does this mean that eigenvalues describe the relation between the documents of and LSI or the internal words of LSI or both ?

Thx in advance.